# liquibase and Oracle 11g varrays

Tags: oracle11g, liquibase

I am completely new to liquibase and I was wondering if I can use it for a project I am working on. For the most part my schema is pretty simple and fairly generic. However, one of the fields is a vArray. Can I define that in liquibase?
Sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't built-in support in liquibase for varrays, but there is an <[sql](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/custom_sql)> tag that lets you do anything you can do through SQL.